# Crontab Won't Save

Tags: centos, cron

Hi I am trying to add a crontab to visit a URL every 15mins. I am using the following code (example URL):

```
* /15 * * * * curl http://google.com
```

I am using the following steps.

1. enter crontab -e on the terminal (I am using a Mac).
2. I try to type in the crontab code from above, I then get the following error.
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

It should be `*/15 * * * *` instead. The extra column is causing the pattern error. This site makes it easy to understand what your schedule will look like -> [crontab guru](https://crontab.guru/#*/15_*_*_*_*)